# mysqldump - create table if not exists

Tags: mysql, sql, windows, powershell

Im using mysqldump with powershell in order to create a backup script for my web app.

This is the command im using for the database dump:

`mysqldump --user=$username --password=$password --log-error=$errorLog --result-file=$backupfile --databases $database`

This creates the required script, however the "IF NOT EXISTS" bit is commented out and I dont know why, or how to stop this behaviour.

line form sqldump:

`CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/`training_web`/*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a hint that mysql only works for that version (and later). 32312 => 3.23.12

Comment: So does this mean that as it is, my script will do the if not exists, as long as im using mysql 3.23.12 or later when i run the script?

Comment: @Brad it will throw a error, since if the DB doesn't support the command, it can not do much about it. With the --force you can skip it, nevertheless im not a fan of default --force (since you wanna know IF something went wrong!).

Answer (score 1):

This is totally normal behaviour that dump doesn't have `IF NOT EXISTS` ... the thing you are seeing is just a directive for MySQL telling it that the command only works in versions 3.23.12 or later.

If you would like to import the dump as it would have `IF NOT EXISTS`, just use `--force` switch.

Comment: So does this mean that as it is, my script will do the if not exists, as long as im using mysql 3.23.12 or later when i run the script?

Comment: Thanks both, as @Rogier mentioned, it seems these "comments" are executed if the version is >=. Thanks again.